# How to get the specific data from jobs payload command in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, queue

I can get the command data from payload on jobs table:

```
$job = DB::table('jobs')->first();
$payload = json_decode($job->payload);
$raw_command = json_decode($job->payload)->data->command;
$command = unserialize($raw_command);
dd($command->notification);
```

The result is:

```
App\Notifications\TenderInProgress {#1527 ▼
  +id: "0788ee9a-62c2-4280-9954-fc1d679228a8"
  +locale: null
  #tender_id: 5
  +connection: null
  +queue: null
  +chainConnection: null
  +chainQueue: null
  +chainCatchCallbacks: null
  +delay: Carbon\Carbon @1678173780 {#1528 ▶}
  +afterCommit: null
  +middleware: []
  +chained: []
}
```

I can dump the value of id:
`dd($command->notification->id)`

But cannot dump the value of tender_id:
Cannot access protected property App\Notifications\TenderInProgress::$tender_id

How can I get the value of tender_id?

Comment: Why are you reading or interacting with that data? If you were using a better query driver like Redis or SQS, you would neraoy not have access to it... Why do you need to read the job's data literally from the database? Think of that data/entry as a black box and you know nothing about it, and the only way to interact with it is by exposed queue commands and jobs. You are doing this because you have an error in your logic, so you need to read a job. Please explain more because your solutions is definitely not reading a job's data directoy from the database...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have a function to send email (using queue) to remind the users when a tender is created. But when tender is canceled, I have to find the specific  jobs according to tender_id to destroy them.

Comment: Then, the job itself has to cancel it, not you. If you are using Laravel 8+, you can use Jobs Middlewares, that middleware should check if the tender is still valid, in that case continue with the normal execution, else delete the job and stop execution. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I have stated on the comments, you have to use a Job Middleware, not read the content of a job (not directly).

Lets create the middleware in `app/Jobs/Middleware` and lets call it `TenderChecker.php`:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Jobs\Middleware;
 
class TenderChecker
{
    public function handle($job, $next)
    {
        if (Tender::findOrFail($job->tender_id)->status !== 'cancelled') {
            return $next($job); 
        }

        $job->delete();
    }
}
```

Do set the right check, I am just giving an example here. The idea is to check if the job should be executed, in your case, if `tender_id` model is not cancelled. I have no idea if you are using `SoftDeletes` or a `status` column, but do the logical check and if it passes the check, do execute `return $next($job);` so it continues checking middlewares until there are no more middlewares and reaches the job for normal execution.

Now, your job would need to have the `middleware` method:

```php
use App\Jos\Middleware\TenderChecker;

class YourJob
{
    // ...
    public function middleware()
    {
        return [new TenderChecker];
    }
}
```

If the middleware passes, then the job is good to go and automatically executes . If the middleware "fails", then it will delete the job, because that is what you want to check/do.

---

Here is an example of Laravel's officials middlewares (so you can see how they are used/built): https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/10.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/Middleware

And here is the official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#job-middleware

Comment: Thank you @matiaslauriti very much. I don't use Job. Currently I use Notification (via email) and implement ShouldQueue. I know there is shouldSend() function, but I want to delete the queue job that tender status is cancelled.

Comment: I did take the time to help you answering. So please, take the time now to read what I wrote and the documentation. The documentation says that the middleware can be added onto notificacions (what you want). I would appreciate an upvote